# ZMQ pattern for requests without replies

Tags: zeromq

I am using ZMQ to allow clients to connect to a server and send commands to it. The commands come in at high frequency, and do not need any reply. I am considering using a REQ/REP socket, but it feels wasteful to send empty replies. I do not wish to use PUB/SUB or PUSH/PULL because I want the clients to initiate the connection. Is there a more suitable pattern than REQ/REP to use here?

Answer (score 2):

> *(cit.:)* because I want the clients to initiate the connection. *( ? )*

One can always let clients to initiate the connection, so using **`PUSH/PULL`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern seems very on target, even with reverse `.bind()/.connect()` calls, or have you meant something else?

If remaining negative about the `PUSH/PULL` ( as observed so far ) for some other reason, one may escape from the strict hard-wired steplocking ( and also from it's risk of falling into unsalvageable deadlocks, associated per-se with it ) of the `REQ/REP`
-- first
by an extended archetype **`XREQ/XREP`** ( see API documentation for implementation details ) 
or
( if using API 4.2+ )
by unlocking the **`REQ`**-hardwired FSA duties via **`.setsockopt( ZMQ_REQ_RELAXED, 1 )`**, given the fact noted above, that `REP` answers will never be sent from the server-side / processed on the `REQ`-side client(s). In case of going this way, be cautious as `ZMQ_REQ_CORRELATE` may get set to 1, where the messages will happen to become multi-frame(d), as the `REQ-id#` will get loaded into the newly injected "service"-frame, before the `REQ`'s client-payload gets onto wire. This may confuse the server-part of the message-receiving / processing code.

For more couragefull designers, may use `PAIR/PAIR` Formal Pattern archetype, as it does not indoctrinate any strict formal behaviour, but read carefully the API specs.

Comment: Oh interesting, I did not realize it was possible to have a PUSH/PULL socket with the PULL side doing the bind() and the PUSH side doing the connect()

Comment: Oh, certainly a smart option, isn't it? Most of the time reversed .bind()/.connect() scenarios are related with the known ZeroMQ-transport-class access-point address v/s the use-cases, where such knowledge is missing ( solving an address agnostic .connect() + dynamic node (re)-discovery ). Anyway, wish you always **enjoy the smart & powerfull tools like the ZeroMQ is**. ( Might be also interested in a younger sister, nanomsg also from Martin SUSTRIK. Worth to mention & compare SWOTs thereof )

Comment: I didn't realize that PUB/SUB can also invert bind/connect :mindblow: Thanks!

Comment: @Gelldur always welcome, yes - it can & is so handy for designing smart distributed heterogeneous SIG / MSG metaplane applications. Stay tuned :o)